# Two HashMap objects override each other's values

Tags: java, session, tomcat, hashmap

I know the title sounds extremely unlikely, but I can't seem to find any other explanation to my problem. Here are the details:

Tomcat 7, Java 7. Tomcat is running some webapps, which are all based on the same template: get a JSON string from session parameter; hand it over to a custom jar (placed in Tomcat/lib folder), which will parse it and store the keys and values in a HashMap; store the custom object as a session parameter. This template part is the same in every webapp. The actual logic of the webapp can get the custom object from the session parameters, and get the values from the HashMap.

The problem happens when two sessions execute the same webapp simultaneously. In this case, the session which initializes the custom object first will get its values overriden by the values from the second session. An example:

Session 1 starts webapp, JSON string in parameter is {"IN.VDN":"86552"}
Session 2 starts webapp, JSON string in parameter is {"IN.VDN":"86113"}
Session 2 initializes custom parser
Session 1 initializes custom parser
Session 2 queries VDN, receives 86113
Session 1 queries VDN, receives 86113 (instead of 86552)

Custom parser is not a Singleton, it is always initiated (new ServiceParamContainer();). The HashMap inside is not static:

```
public class ServiceParamContainer {

    private HashMap<String, ServiceParamElement> params;
```

And it's also always initialized in the constructor:

```
params = new HashMap<String, ServiceParamElement>();
```

The session itself cannot be faulty, because the JSON string doesn't change, it contains the same value even after the custom object returns the wrong value. The custom object also seems to be good, because normally it works fine,  it only breaks if the same webapp is executed simultaneously in multiple sessions. Also, I logged the value returned by toString() in the separate sessions, and it was different, which makes me believe that the objects themselves are not the same. I'm not sure about the underlying HashMap though. Either the same object is used in the separate sessions, or they are written to the same memory area, I'm not sure. I find it suspicious because in this case the HashMaps contain exactly the same keys, so I guess Java is optimizing something here.

Do you have any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Your process is unclear to me, i think you should clarify it before expecting an answer. But i bet your error is due to an non ThreadSafe class.

Comment: Can you post more code ? Try using a concurrentHashMap.